# How to create a batch file that starts an executable with parameters

Tags: batch-file, command-line, rethinkdb

I am trying to create a batch file that opens a RethinkDB database.I need to execute it like this

```
rethinkdb.exe  -http-port <portno>
```

How can i do this from a batch file?I just wanted to start the script.The port will be hard-coded in the script.

I tried:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\username\Desktop\personal\wsrethink"
start "" rethinkdb /path:"C:\Users\username\Desktop\personal\wsrethink\rethinkdb.exe" --http-port 9300
timeout 10
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@echo off
start "" /D "C:\Users\username\Desktop\personal\wsrethink" rethinkdb.exe --http-port 9300
timeout 10
pause
```